# MassTransit JobConsumer: (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'

Tags: entity-framework, rabbitmq, masstransit, sqlexception, consumer

I try to start [MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumer](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers) on EntityFramework Core, but having strange error

> (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone [MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumer](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers)
2. Remove PostgreSQL an install EntityFrameworkCore
3. Command Update-Database creates a correct database
   [image]
4. Start project `JobService.Service`
   [image]
5. Post request from Postman (response is valid):
   [image]
6. RabbitMQ accept requests:
   [image]
7. But error occured during processing (in console):
   [image]

Please, anyone help me to understand what is happened.

You can see repository on [github with EntityFrameworkCore storage implemented](https://github.com/Calabonga/MassTransit-JobConsumer)

P.S. With default configuration the error was different
[image]

### [Update 1]

After I changed `PostgresLockStatementProvider` to `SqlServerLockStatementProvider` (Thanks to Chris Patterson for help). But I`ve got another error:
[image]

### [Update 2]

After I was installed plugin for RabbitMQ **everything became works fine with EntityFrameworkCore too**! (Thanks to Chris Patterson)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change to SQL Server, you'd need to change the EF Core configuration to `UseSqlServer`, you also need to [remove the PostgreSQL lock provider](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers/blob/master/src/JobService.Service/Startup.cs#L55) (the default lock provider is SqlServer). There are three lines where this change is needed, one for each state machine.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I changed `PostgresLockStatementProvider` to `SqlServerLockStatementProvider`. But I`ve got another error.

Comment: MT-Fault-Message: The payload was not found: MassTransit.MessageSchedulerContext

Comment: You need to have a message scheduler configured, I was fairly sure there was one in the sample.

Comment: Sorry Chris, but I don't think so. When I ran your sample (w/o anything changes) I've got an error "The payload was not found: MassTransit.MessageSchedulerContext". Or is it message scheduler required too?

Comment: My bad. A didn`t commit the repository https://github.com/Calabonga/MassTransit-JobConsumer. But now it was done. It has sample code with EntityFramework Core implementation.

Comment: Well, you didn't keep this rather important line: `cfg.UseRabbitMqMessageScheduler();`

Comment: Thanks Chris, you are right, I skipped line cfg.UseRabbitMqMessageScheduler(). But after I added this line, there is another error: 
**R-RETRY rabbitmq://localhost/worker/job 7a000000-9a3c-0005-2031-08d86934701d MassTransit.Context.RetryConsumeContext<MassTransit.Contracts.JobService.JobAttemptStarted>
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=503, text='COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'', classId=40, methodId=10**

Please, how I could fix this issue?
(commited to git)

Comment: You likely don't have the RabbitMQ delayed exchange plug-in installed/enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! After I was installed plugin for RabbitMQ everything became works fine with EntityFrameworkCore too!